# how to enable SHA256 in openssl 0.9.7c

Tags: java, openssl

I am using openssl commands as process in JAVA. and executing it as proc.exec();
I want to use SHA-256 algorithm but I have openssl 0.9.7c where SHA256 is not available by default.  how can i make use of it.

Comment: openssl 0.9.7c is 10+ years old. Upgrade to the current version.

Comment: Cannot you just do SHA256 in Java?

Comment: no I have use these as process only in my application..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call out into openssl to do SHA-256 calculations, this can be done in Java.

For example, include Commons Codec and then it's as simple as

```
byte[] sha = DigestUtils.sha256(byteArrayOrInputStreamWithData);
```

or

```
String shaHex = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(byteArrayOrInputStreamWithData);
```